# Huge Image Problem

Tags: images, printing, jpeg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Good software for printing a poster?](https://superuser.com/questions/210793/good-software-for-printing-a-poster)

Hi All,

I have a great problem , and I have no idea how to solve it , I have create a chart (Mind map) in Smart draw, what I want now is to print this Mind map , the mind map is very large when i Export it as Image I have a big image , so can any one tell me if there is any software that can divide this big image into small parts of size (A4) to be able to print it on several papers and show it to my boss

please help as soon as you can

Thanks in Advance

Comment: @The Communist Duck: is correct; however, there's a package called ImageMagick that could carve up your image for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) for this purpose but you should check this out.
http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_tile.  It looks like just what you need. It is a truly amazing program once you get the hang of it.